# QGIS 3x Label doesn't move when moving the point feature

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to move my label and basically set some expressions for it.

Unfortunately since I started to use the data attribute table auxiliary columns for location and movement, my layer is not really editable this way.

First of all I can't move the selected point layer, to which the label is assigned, like below (see the yellow dot).

[image]

Secondly the label placement (offset) doesn't work anymore.

In turn, my street name shifts from one side to another as the scale changes.

[image]

All expressions regarding to font size algorithms, rotation etc stopped working beyond this point.

Is there any way to combine the auxiliary rotation with rotation and offset set by expression?